# Flask-migrate No changes in schema detected

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am trying to understand how flask and sqlalchemy works.Below is my app structure

[image]

**init**.py contains

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
import User

# Create a login manager object
login_manager = LoginManager()

app = Flask(__name__)

# Often people will also separate these into a separate config.py file
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)
```

model.py

```
from test import db
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin



class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    # Create a table in the db
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)


    def __init__(self, email, username, password,first_name,last_name):
        self.email = email
```

and app.py

```
# This is app.py, this is the main file called.
from test import app
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and I am using below commands to create tables

1. set FLASK_APP=
2. flask db init
3. flask db migrate -m

But flask migrate is not detecting table and displays below message

[image]

I am unable to figure how to resolve this issue.Could someone please highlight what I am doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: import ```db``` as well in your app.py like ```from test import app, db``` Let me know if it works

Comment: No. It didn't work.

Comment: did you import your models anywhere? I don't see any `import model` in your code.

Comment: It worked after importing model.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `import model` in `__init__.py`

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
import User

# Create a login manager object
login_manager = LoginManager()

app = Flask(__name__)

# Often people will also separate these into a separate config.py file
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)
from app import model
```

This is because `model.py` depends on `__init__.py`